# How to create class instance without using variable value?

Tags: java, swing, plugins

I am a developer , recently i am developing a java application. 
        This application generated a number reports and it's application is updated regularly for implementing new report feature in application.

So i want integrate plugins system like Eclipse or others tools in which we can install new plugins  according to our requirement.

There some questions have in mind to implement it like -

**Q. 1 - How to create class instance without using variable value ?**

```
 For example -


public class A {
  public static void main(String arg[])
     {
           int data = 0;
           String CName = "B";

          B ob1 = new B()  //valid ways
          data = ob1.addMy();  //valid ways

           CName ob2 = new CName();  // My required ways
           data = ob2.addMy(); // My required ways            
     }
}
class B
     {
      int addMy()
         {
           int a =90;
           return a;
         }
      }
```

Actually .class will be saved in packages dynamically so i am saving class name in database after then i want to use this class name string to create instance(object) for accessing saved class members. **Please give me suggestion if possible**

**Q. 2 - How to best ways to implement Plugin features in java application. Please give me example if possible .**

Please help me 
Thanks All.

Comment: Read up on classloading and reflection.  You can dynamically load a class using `Class.forName` for example

Comment: Eclipse, and many applications that dynamically install modules, uses [OSGi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi). What you're talking about is somewhat hacky - it would work but likely cause a PerGen leak,

Comment: Also consider deploying via [tag:java-web-start] for periodic updates.

Answer (score 0):

For

> Q. 1 - How to create class instance without using variable value ?

You can Probably have a look on these:

> Apache Commons JCI's
>
> 1. ReloadingClassLoader
> 2. FilesystemAlterationMonitor

Below links might be useful:

1. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jci/apidocs/org/apache/commons/jci/ReloadingClassLoader.html
2. [Apache Commons JCI ReloadingClassLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203383/apache-commons-jci-reloadingclassloader)